# Power BI Deployment Pipeline - Compare feature via API

Tags: powershell, powerbi

Power BI Deployment Pipelines offers a great visual solution to deploying reports and datasets from one environment to another. Unfortunately, I have some unique DevOps use cases and cannot leverage this tool.

I was wondering if the "Compare" functionality is available as a public API. It would be great if there is a way to programmatically (PowerShell etc.) compare two Power BI reports / datasets. Any input is appreciated.

[image]

Comment: What exactly do you want to compare?

Comment: I need a simple checksum comparison for the report and the dataset. Similar to how Power BI Deployment Pipeline marks a report or dataset as 'different' using the 'compare' functionality.